# how to change bitmap image width and height in createjs

Tags: javascript, game-development, createjs, 2d-games

I have created a game in createjs. For images I am using bitmap to load them. I am able to give them positioning in my grid. I'm trying to change its width and height but its not working.

```
// this is where i am loading the image. 
  buttonSolve = new createjs.Bitmap(loader.getResult("buttonCategory"));
  centerReg1(buttonSolve);
// i have tried a bunch of methods but none worked.

  // buttonSolve.setDrawSize(200, 100);
  // buttonSolve.sourceRect = { width: 280, height: 150 };
  // buttonSolve.width = buttonSize.w;
  // buttonSolve.height = buttonSize.h;
  // buttonSolve.setBounds(0, 0, 250, 400);

// this is centerReg1 function: 

function centerReg1(obj) {
  obj.regX = 195;
  obj.regY = 80;
  // obj.setBounds(0, 0, 250, 100);
  // obj.scaleX = -2;
  // obj.x = canvasW / 2 - 120;
  // obj.y = (canvasH / 100) * 75;
  // obj.sourceRect = { width: 280, height: 150 };
}
```

kindly someone tell me how to do this!

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure

but you can solve this issue by using `scaleX` & `scaleY` properties of
`buttonSolve` bitmap

```
buttonSolve.scaleX = newWidth / originalWidth;
buttonSolve.scaleY = newHeight / originalHeight;
```

**2nd method**

```
buttonSolve.setTransform(0, 0, newWidth/originalWidth, newHeight/originalHeight);
```

Here

1. `originalWidth` & `originalHeight` are the original `width` & `height`
2. `newWidth` & `newHeight` are the updated `width` & `height`

Comment: it worked fine  and width and height are being set now

Comment: It would be great for other users if you accept this answer